# How to generate items from same table depending in a condition in select list ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So here is the problem: I have a `product` table with columns `ID`, `Name`, `Type` (Brand or Product) and `ParentProduct` (Select List).

Now imaging that the `Products` table got some records in which some are (Type) Products and others are Brands, what I want is that while inserting a new `Product` with type = Product then `ParentProduct` shows Products with type Brand, whereas inserting a product as brand makes the parentproduct select list disabled.

Comment: One option, add a bool property (i.e. IsParentProductEnabled) to your view model that uses only a getter to return a whether or not ParentProduct should be disabled based on the Type propert.  You could then use this property in your view using razor to decide whether the select list is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to get the `Type` value and then judge to disable the `ParentProduct` or not.

Here is a simple demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ParentProduct { get; set; }
}
public class Brand
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View(Create.cshtml):

```
@model Product
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Select a Type</option>
                    <option value="Brand">Brand</option>
                    <option value="Product">Product</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ParentProduct" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ParentProduct" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Brand" disabled>
                    <option>Select a Brand</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#Type").change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        console.log(v);
        if (v == "Product") {
            $("#ParentProduct").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $("#ParentProduct").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        ViewBag.Brand = new SelectList(_context.Brands.ToList(), "ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]